I'm struggling to make an ik for a robotic leg
I've used Ik's before on human rigs but never anything else. I'm making a robotic leg thing and the Ik works but I'm not sure how I'd keep certain objects from stretching and deforming well keeping it working as intended. I'm not really sure how to explain it so I'll include my blend file. I've so far tried messing with weight painting, vertex groups, and the actually armature I may have done something wrong when trying to mess with them. Could somebody help me fix this? I'd Greatly appreciate it. (Nothing's named yet so sorry in advance)


Delete all vertex groups an all meshes you have. And use "bone" instead of automatic weights or weight painting.
A robot has no "dynamic" mesh - it's all rigid, right?
So after deleting your vertex groups do this:

select one part of the robot
shift-select the armature -> pose mode -> select the corresponding bone
ctrl -p -> bone

repeat that for all bones.
I would recommend moving each bone after parenting to check whether it works.

You can also join all the pieces together, select all in Edit mode and remove all the vertices from all groups, then assign them correctly.

